# tableau totals on calculated fields

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau I'm displaying adjusted sales levels per account (rows) by group and product (columns) as a conditional calculated field AGG(adjusted $) where ADJUSTED $ is computed as follows:

```
if AVG([SALETYPE]) = 1 then ADJUSTED $ = SUM([$_SALES])
elseif AVG([SALETYPE]) = 2 then ADJUSTED $ = SUM([$_SALES]) * 0.5
else 0
END
```

This works great at a granular sale level (per account by product/group), but Tableau's aggregations/Totals are very confusing to me:

1) When I add table-down Grand Totals, it gives me unadjusted values (i.e. does not adjust SALETYPE 2 downward by 50%) until I add one of my filter dimensions  (product family) as a column, at which point the Grand Totals are correct.

2) When I add subtotals across rows, it also gives me unadjusted values. When I add my Row dimension as a Filter and select the whole available universe, nothing changes. However, if I deselect all and select ONE individual account to filter by, the subtotals are accurately computed. I've tried adding ZN() to all my functions to deal with null values but to no avail.

Any thoughts/recommendations how to deal with aggregating conditional values much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set and expected results?